# Trying to post score with scores api from an iOS app, but app access_token is required

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I have an iOS game that wants to publish user scores to Facebook. I use lastest Facebook SDK from git.

The app is in the Games category, and marked as Native/Desktop app.

The iOS bundle is set correctly (if I set it wrong, my app can't log-in).

I request publish_actions permission from the user and it succeeds.

But when I try to post a new score via requestGraphPath of USER_ID/scores (or me/scores) I get an error requesting the app access_token.

I understand that this is considered as a client-app and the app authentication is done via the Facebook SDK. So the access_token is a combined one (and encrypted?) and should work.
(putting the App Secret Key inside my app and patching the SDK to handle it isn't a good idea)

On the other hand, posting high scores via the new Open Graph works perfectly (I use the default High Score action and it works), but I need to wait for the approval in order to go live...

What am I missing about the Scores API?

Comment: Hi, have you already found a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

On facebook your app must be WEB-type.
Work only with USER_ID and app access_token 
(example 221179161233395|O9Wwt7hmowV2Bt3k5yVAy2SInTU)

Comment: Are you suggesting that the help text of the 'App Type' field is misleading?

Comment: After changing the app type to Web, the scores API does not work